# Return 403 or 201 if a field is not writable

Tags: rest, api-design

What is the best practice for a response if the user tries to write to a field he or she is not allowed?

Imagine the user wants to create a resource, for example a pizza: `POST /pizza`

The body:

```
{
  "name": "Hawaii",
  "base": "tomato sauce",
  "firstMain": "ham",
  "secondMain": "pineapple",
  "cheese": true
}
```

Problem is, you can't put `secondMain` on a pizza (because its pineapple). What's better? Return a 403 error with the message that `field secondMain is not writable` or return a 201 with the created pizza but without the `secondMain`?

What's the best practice for this problem? Didn't found anything on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a `403` with a proper error response would work best. Saying `201` but creating something different then what they originally wanted would probably lead to a unhappy customer. I know I'd be annoyed if my pizza didn't come with pineapple and that's what I ordered.

Really guess it varies on a case by case basis depending on your expected result and what your client is expecting to happen. Just make sure to specify in your documentation that extra data sent up with requests that isn't writable will throw an error.

etc

`403` response: `{error: {"secondMain": "unknown field", "exampleField": "expected but missing"}}`

Comment: sounds good. Actually I'm the customer using an API. The API returns a 403 but only specifying the not writable field with an id. As I don't have insight into the internal id mappings I wondered if that is a best practice. Thank you!

Comment: @0x4b50 ah! I would definitely send them an email, asking for better error responses. probably a feedback they've never gotten. Cheers.

Comment: I did. Unfortunately they are not really fast in responding :/